# Color of Image changes to white between 2 positions using Color.Lerp - Unity

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, image, color

Hi I have an empty object `barHolder` that I move between `10` and `98` on x-axis. It has 2 child images `roundBar` and `bar`. I am trying to change the color of `roundBar` and `bar` when the object is moving. On `x=10` the the color will be red and on `x=98` it will be green. Here is what I have done so far:

```
    public GameObject meterBarHolder;

    public GameObject barRoundHead;
    public GameObject bar;

    public Text meterSpeedText;
    int currentSpeed;

    Color maxColor = new Color(21, 193, 25, 255);
    Color minColor = new Color(229, 85, 85, 255);

    float totalSpeed;

    float speedPercentage;

    float pos;
    //--------------//

    private void Start()
    {
        totalSpeed = (float)PlayerPrefs.GetInt("speed");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        currentSpeed = int.Parse(meterSpeedText.text);

        speedPercentage = (float)currentSpeed / totalSpeed;

        pos = 88 * speedPercentage;

        if(pos < 10)
        {
            meterBarHolder.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3(10f, 0f, 0f);
            changeColor(0);
        }
        else if(pos > 98)
        {
            meterBarHolder.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3(98f, 0f, 0f);
            changeColor(1);
        }
        else
        {
            meterBarHolder.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3(pos, 0f, 0f);
            changeColor(speedPercentage);
        }

    }

    void changeColor(float x)
    {
        bar.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.Lerp(minColor, maxColor, x);
        barRoundHead.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.Lerp(minColor, maxColor, x);
    }
```

The problem is that when ever I click play the color changes to white.

For reproducing the problem `totalSpeed=120` and `meterSpeedText` changes between  `0` and `120`. The rest are calculated in the code.

Here is a gif to give an idea what I am trying to do:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using [Color](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html) as if it was a [Color32](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32.html).

- Color uses (float) values between 0 and 1
- Color32 uses (byte) values between 0 and 255.

So a value greater then one is clamped to 1 for the shader, new Color(21, 193, 25, 255) is therefore to the shader the same color as new Color(1, 1, 1, 1) a.k.a. white.

So to fix this problem, you should either use Color32 instead of Color or change your input to float values ranging between 0 and 1.

Color32 can also be [implicitly casted](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32-operator_Color32.html) to a Color, so this would be the simplest solution:

```
Color maxColor = new Color32(21, 193, 25, 255);
Color minColor = new Color32(229, 85, 85, 255);
```

Comment: thanks man I use values from 0 to 1 and its working now. thanks a lot.